# Android : Second Navigation View is not recognized by Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using two Navigation View in my app, second ( right ) one is via a custom component. Its working fine during manual testing, however espresso doesn't recognize it during testing. Second NAV is kept invisible and activated it onCreate method of corresponding method.

I tried to test first navigation view using same appraoch, it works fine..

Below is relevant code snippets and logs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_left_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

   <com.example.tt0401.NavigationViewRight
    android:id="@+id/nav_right_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_right_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

//code inside  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method to method to make it visible 
`drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, navigationViewRight);`

//Espresso Test method

```
@Test
public void navigationDrawer() throws Exception {
fabAddClick();
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open(Gravity.END));
onView(withId(R.id.nav_right_view)).perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(1000003));
}
```

Espresso Failure Logs

01-02 12:25:58.228 18570-18585/? I/TestRunner: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click on menu item with id' on view 'with id: com.example.tt0401:id/nav_right_view'.
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
                                                   at com.example.tt0401.RecordActivity3Test.navigationDrawer(RecordActivity3Test.java:135)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
                                                   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                                                   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
                                                   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
                                                   at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
                                                   at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
                                                   at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                                                   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                                                   at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
                                                   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
                                               (is assignable from class: class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.)
                                               Target view: "NavigationViewRight{id=2131624075, res-name=nav_right_view, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=980, height=2100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1440.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"
                                                   at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                at androi
01-02 12:25:58.228 18570-18585/? I/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
01-02 12:25:58.231 18570-18585/? I/TestRunner: finished: navigationDrawer(com.example.tt0401.RecordActivity3Test)
01-02 12:25:58.250 18570-18585/? I/TestRunner: run finished: 1 tests, 1 failed, 0 ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to make this invisible instead of gone inside `<com.example.tt0401.NavigationViewRight>`

```
  android:visibility="gone"
```